# android - Why mapObjectClickEvent not fire on clicking the mapObject?

Tags: android, amcharts

I am using amCharts library to show map in my android app.I have lots of problems in pinch in/out and dragging ,...
I am trying to handle the events to solve that problems.
but when I pinch in or pinch out the map, the `mapObjectClick` event will be fired and then by clicking on that `mapObject` the click event fire but the `mapObjectClick` does not fire,I dont know why, and what can I do?

Comment: what a excellent question... exact my problem

Answer (score 1):

fortunately I found the problem.I set allowClickOnSelectedObject property to false,so the mapObjectClick event would not fired for second time.